# How do I get my geom_line() data to show up on my dual y-axis bar/line chart in ggplot2 (R)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom

I'm having trouble getting my line graph to plot correctly on my dual y-axis plot. It will plot the points just fine but won't plot the line connecting all the points (only two points currently). There are no missing or NA values in my dataset so it's not that. I'm not entirely sure what the issue is.

This is what I have:

```
#import dataset
weather_phase1 =read.csv("Gobabebmet_phase1.csv",header=TRUE)

#value to transform data
coeff <- 100

p1 <- ggplot(weather_phase1, aes(x=Datetime)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y=Fog), stat = "identity", fill='#54b8e3') +
  geom_line(aes(y=Humidity / coeff), color = "#bf5aed") +
  geom_point(aes(y=Humidity / coeff)) +
  ylim(0,1) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Fog (mm)", sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*coeff, name="Humidity (%)")) +
  xlab("Time") + 
  ylab("Fog (mm)") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 20)) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
p1
p1 + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

And this is what it spit out:
[image: bar plot with line plot on top, dual y-axis of fog and humidity]

Comment: You need to convert your date-time strings into actual date-time objects. At the moment, R is treating them as a categorical variable. Try `weather_phase1$Datetime <- as.POSIXct(weather_phase1$Datetime, format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M")` and run your plot code again.

Comment: If you wanted to keep your axis as factors (maybe you have a situation where you don't want the points spaced proportionately with time, for instance), you could add `group = 1` (or any singular value) inside `geom_line(aes(...))` to signal that the observations should be plotted as one series, so that a line is shown. ggplot2 is using the factor x value to infer that the different data points are from different categories and should not be connected.